# how to get ID back from a URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a URL like below

```
/pages/edit_product/11
```

In my action `edit_product` how can I get the id 11 So that I can do @p = `Product.find_by_id(11)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Any parameter passed with url is available in the controller action and views in params hash.

To grab the id from the url, you can do params[:id] in your controller#edit_product action or view. So you can get the product by

```
@p = Product.find_by_id(params[:id])
```